# wp_list_comments adds unnecessary elements

Tags: comments

**wp_list_comments** adds *UL* / *OL* or *DIV* which do not serve for my thema.

how do I prevent this??

screeshots:
http://d.pr/i/1bpn

my code http://pastebin.com/bQxUyZTs

tnx!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add your own `<li>` when using callback. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments (see bottom info)